# heroku free dyno cannot access tiktok?

Tags: heroku, network

I have write a playwright to scrape tiktok videos,but it seems the server `s network to tiktok is blocked?
https://www.tiktok.com/@mariavoitenko957/video/7073090495928339718
there is no error in log panel

```
2022-03-12T11:56:10.510077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?app=index" host=tiktokdownloadapi.herokuapp.com request_id=28a6ed05-7b2d-4ca5-8fdf-1dcda08a8070 fwd="50.7.60.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=741 protocol=https

2022-03-12T11:56:10.509285+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.39.55 - - [12/Mar/2022 11:56:10] "GET /?app=index HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2022-03-12T11:56:10.927332+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.190 - - [12/Mar/2022 11:56:10] "GET /?app=index HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2022-03-12T11:56:10.926527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?app=index" host=tiktokdownloadapi.herokuapp.com request_id=7b9e0d96-fea7-49ed-8c80-89d7e1c4a638 fwd="50.7.60.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=147 protocol=https

2022-03-12T11:56:11.943943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?app=index" host=tiktokdownloadapi.herokuapp.com request_id=d6acbbae-0a4f-486b-96c2-409ae905dfa9 fwd="50.7.60.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=147 protocol=https

2022-03-12T11:56:11.944545+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.190 - - [12/Mar/2022 11:56:11] "GET /?app=index HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2022-03-12T11:56:12.961070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?app=index" host=tiktokdownloadapi.herokuapp.com request_id=f4e31ad4-c01a-4455-827b-3449a8c1204d fwd="50.7.60.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=147 protocol=https

2022-03-12T11:56:12.961892+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.190 - - [12/Mar/2022 11:56:12] "GET /?app=index HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2022-03-12T11:56:14.403412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?app=index" host=tiktokdownloadapi.herokuapp.com request_id=73ae5f49-e196-49f6-997b-9a286305e755 fwd="50.7.60.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=147 protocol=https

2022-03-12T11:56:14.404264+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.190 - - [12/Mar/2022 11:56:14] "GET /?app=index HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2022-03-12T11:56:15.402154+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.190 - - [12/Mar/2022 11:56:15] "GET /?app=index HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2022-03-12T11:56:15.401304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?app=index" host=tiktokdownloadapi.herokuapp.co
```

Comment: Please use [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/371419/edit) & add relevant code as based on the details provided it's hard for us to tell whats exactly wrong.

Comment: which and what info should I provide ,since other website it can scrape  and sure there is no other debug info at all .  and you can tell me how to debug this free dyno network with tiktok